# world coordinates to UI cordinates and vice versa?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have canvas in screen space overlay render mode. So what i want is when user touches to screen some image must appear exactly in the same position where user touched the screen. My image should be in UI layer. I would have achieved the result if my canvas was in screen space Camera render mode by following..

```
Image img = null // I assign it via the inspector

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector2 point;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle((RectTransform)img.rectTransform.parent,
                                                                 Input.mousePosition, canvasCamera, out point);
        img.rectTransform.anchorPosition = point;
   }
}
```

but i want to achieve the same result in screen space overlay render mode because i have alot of UI components that doesn't fit in the screen. plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
[SerializeField] private Image image = null;
void Update()
{
    image.position = Input.mousePosition;
}
```

this will make the image follow the mouse pointer.The pivot point defines what position of the image will be right under the mouse pointer.

Comment: i don't want image to follow the mouse pointer i just want to place the image in canvas where touched in detected.

Comment: What I showed there is that you do not need to convert anything to get the UI object at the mouse position. Just place it in your input code you show and that should do what you are after, that is placing the UI item where the click occured